# expansion for $1-|t|$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, fourier-series, wavelets

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support with exactly one maximum.  Form the functions 
$$
f_{m,k}(x)=f^m\left(x-\frac{k}{2^m}\right)
$$

I am wondering if one can expand function $B(t)=1-|t|$, $t \in \mathbb{R}$ (this function called $B_1$ -spline) in terms of $f_{m,k}$, i.e. something like $1-|t|=\sum_{k,m}c_kf_{m,k} $

Thank you.

Comment: do you mean local maximum or a global one?

Comment: also, do you mean composition or multiplication?

Comment: @tomasz: I ment global maximum.And its composition.